# Ubuntu - how to increase the size of RAID 1

Tags: 22.04

I have Software RAID1 running on Ubuntu 22.04.

```
lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0  100G  0 disk  
├─sda1          8:1    0    1M  0 part  
├─sda2          8:2    0   50G  0 part  
└─sda3          8:3    0   10G  0 part  [SWAP]
sdb             8:16   0  100G  0 disk  
└─sdb1          8:17   0  100G  0 part  
  └─md127       9:127  0   40G  0 raid1 
    └─md127p1 259:1    0   40G  0 part  /
sdc             8:32   0  250G  0 disk  
└─md0           9:0    0  250G  0 raid1 
  └─md0p1     259:0    0   50G  0 part  /var
sdd             8:48   0  250G  0 disk  
└─md0           9:0    0  250G  0 raid1 
  └─md0p1     259:0    0   50G  0 part  /var
sr0            11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Above is the layout of my disks. AS you can see I have 100GB but I use only 40GB in md127.

How can I increase that to maximum capacity?

I tried:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/md127p1
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem is already 10476288 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

and

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/md127
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/md127
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Same applies for md0p1 as you can see it is stopped at 50GB while it have 250GB available. How can I extend those ?

Comment: I believe you do it all with `mdadm` to grow the RAID partitions to the maximum size.  `sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md0 -z max` and or `sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md127 -z max`.  Then you should be able to grow the partitions with in.  However, you might need to boot to a live USB to perform this as it may fail when performing on a running system and corrupt your data.